# Как получить сообщение через vkAPI (именно его текст) и сразу вложить в переменную? PHP

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

Как получить сообщение через vkAPI (именно текст сообщения) и сразу вложить в переменную для дальнейшей работы с ней?

Answer (score 0):

Ознакомьтесь с примером от самих ВКонтакте: https://vk.com/dev/callback_api_2

Если кратко:

```
// Получаем JSON-тело входящего POST-запроса
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); 

// Тип события
$event_type = $data->type

// Обрабатываем
switch ($event_type) {
    case 'message_new': 
        // Пишем текст сообщения в переменную
        $message = $data->object->body
}
```

Это, конечно же, если вы работаете с Callback API от ВКонтакте, а не через LongPoll.